# Почему этот короткий код JavsScript работает

Tags: javascript

Учу JS, наткнулся на такой пример и завис(((

Объясните мне пожалуйста смысл и логику того, почему этот код работает. 
По моему разумению он работать не должен по 2 причинам: 
1) не определена переменная "n"
2) addThree не может принять на себя аргумент, так как это переменная, а не функция.

Но код верный и работает. 
Что не так с моим пониманием JS?

```js
let c = 4
function addX(x) {
  return function(n) {
     return n + x
  }
}
const addThree = addX(3)
let d = addThree(c)
console.log('example partial application', d)
```

Comment: Почитатйе про "Замыкания" и тогда станет понятно где "n" определена и почему это работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

он работать не должен по 2 причинам:

> addThree не может принять на себя аргумент, так как это переменная, а не функция.

Есть два вида объявления функций: *Function Declaration* и *Function Expression*. Первый вид, это когда пишется так:

```
function hello(world) {
  return 'Значение аргумента: ' +  world;
}

console.log(hello('Привет!'));
```

Второй вид объявляется так:

```
let hello = function(параметры) {
  // тело функции
};

hello(Параметр);
```

> не определена переменная "n"

Раз с первым пунктом определились, смотрим на второй.

```
const addThree = addX(3)
```

Т.к. `addX` возвращает не конкретное значение, а опять функцию (а мы уже узнали про объявление *Function Expression*), то по факту ни что иное как

```
const addThree = function(n) {
     return n + 3
}
```

Где переменная `x` по факту подставилась непосредственно в выражение. 
Почему так - читай про [Замыкания](https://learn.javascript.ru/closure).
И теперь у нас по факту имеется  функция `addThree`, которую для наглядности можно переписать вот так:

```
function addThree(n) {
     return n + 3;
}
```

Поэтому в итоге  в переменную `d` получаем результат, возвращаемый из функции `addThree`.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ по первой части понял, но постигнуть смысл замыкания пока не получается( Согласен, что function addThree(n) { return n + 3; } , но почему именно переменная "с" подставляется в функцию вместо определенной в ней "n"?

Comment: @Dmitry так `n` это имя аргумента. он может быть назван хоть `sdfhsdkjfhsdkjfsdghk`. А переменная `c` содержит значение и передается в функцию именно значение переменной. Что и попадает в аргумент `n`. Это уже не относится к замыканию это уже относится к банальной работе с функцией. Потому что итог будет: `d = addThree(4);` . Это совсем база языка. Если вы её не знаете, то стоит почитать книги по основам

Answer (score 2):

```js
'use strict';

let c = 4;

function addX(x) {
  return function(n) {
     return n + x;
  };
}

//в переменной addThree будет храниться результат вызова функции addX
//вызов addX(3) вернет функцию, и сохранить контекст (значение параметра x = 3)
const addThree = addX(3);

//переменная - это всего лишь "контейнер для данных". в данный момент в переменно addThree находиться функция.
//вызов addThree(с) вернет значение выражения n + x. x = 3, n = 4.

let d = addThree(c);

console.log('example partial application', d);
```

**P.S:** Не забывай про `;`, и пиши желательно с использованием `'use strict';`.

**Полезные ссылки:**

- [Объявление Function Expression](https://learn.javascript.ru/function-declaration-expression#function-expression)
- [Замыкание](https://learn.javascript.ru/closure)
- [Советы по стилю кода](https://learn.javascript.ru/coding-style)